# Is there a hierarchy to image schemas?

Tags: ontology, cognitive-sciences, cognitive-psychology, cognition

[Image schemas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_schema) are primitive concepts that are studied in diverse fields such as linguistics, psychology, cognitive linguistics, neuroscience.

> The influences of image schemas is not only seen in cognitive
> linguistics and developmental psychology, but also in interface design
> and more recently, the theory has become of increased interest in
> artificial intelligence and cognitive robotics.

It seems to me though that certain concepts assumes the existence of others and therefore that there should be a hierarchical structure to experience. For example one might recognize a schema A:*(origen, first principal, here, ground, start)* and a schema B:*(movement, distance, difference, distinction, separation)* and C:*(direction, location, quantification, qualification, separateness)*

Consider that (C) can only exist once there is the existence of (B) allowing (C) to reference something distinct from (A). And (B) can only exist if there is a place to start from (A). We have thus created a hierarchy with at least three levels.

**Question: Has anyone created such a hierarchical table of schemas?**

*See also [semantic primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_primes)*

Comment: Which one of (A), (B), and (C) is at the top of the hierarchy?

Comment: From the top A,B,C.

Comment: To stay only in the schemes you propose, Doesn't *location* stand at the top, and *here* and *origin* below it? Wrt to generality that is.

Comment: @Methadont Location is a point within a framework, it has properties like direction and coordinates. The (A) )pre-exist the framework, it is the start of building framework/structure. You can think of it as the zero point on a coordinate system it has no dimension.

Comment: Here and origin are both locations. But a location can be given to all points. Location is general, here and origin are particular.

Comment: @Methadont What properties does location have?

Comment: A location is an arbitrary point in space(time). What properties has a point in spacetime? It has no direction on its own. For that, other points must be there. Direction is a property of two points. You can never draw a line from one point if no other points are there. There is a hierarchy in your schemas. But you have to consider what comes first.  A relationship or the things related?